# Angle brackets containing interface in class declaration

Tags: reactjs, typescript, class, interface

I'm learning typescript and I'm following this tutorial: https://blog.alexdevero.com/react-and-typescript-pt3/.

When he speaks about the interface he use it in react in the following way:

```
// Create interface for class component props
interface PropsInterface {
  heading: string;
}

// Create interface for class component state
interface StateInterface {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
}

class MyApp extends React.Component<PropsInterface, StateInterface> {

// This state annotation is optional
  // it is for better type inference
  state: StateInterface = {
    firstName: 'Andrew',
    lastName: 'Coboll'
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.heading} {this.state.firstName} {this.state.lastName}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

What's the angle brackets containing the interfaces means?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

It means that your props object's type is PropsInterface, and your state object's type is StateInterface.By doing this you do not need to do this.

```
 state: StateInterface = {
    firstName: 'Andrew',
    lastName: 'Coboll'
  }
```

You just can use like this:

```
 state = {
    firstName: 'Andrew',
    lastName: 'Coboll'
  }
```

it already know s your state's type when u add types in that angle brackets

Answer (score 0):

I understood the solution right after post it, so I share it here:

All the post I read say to see the generic on https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html.

I read the doc but what I can't understand since now it's the is not the class I'm creating the generic but the Component class.

So I expected the Component class is declared, conceptually, like this:

```
class Component<P, S>{
    props: P;
    state: S
}
```

So when I create a class that extends Component I set the interface with angle brackets